# If GIT is decentralized, how conflicts are solved?

Tags: git, svn, git-push

Using SVN, I can see the main difference between it and GIT is that the repository is decenralized. But if developers work offline with whole branches, commit changes and push it at some point - isnt it much more problematic, conflict-wise? I probably miss some pieces of the puzzle and would be gratefl for explanation.

Comment: see http://githowto.com/resolving_conflicts

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on **how** Git is used. In many cases all developers share a common **origin**; that is a common **central repository**. In that case; conflict solving happens mostly in the same way as with svn:

1. make sure your local master branch is up to date with remote data (from the central repository)
2. Make sure your local changes apply to the master branch (and resolve any conflicts locally if necessary)
3. push changes to the central repository.

Atlassian makes nice tutorials about possible workflows. This one is called the [centralized workflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/centralized-workflow/).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot push until the branch on your local repository is up to date with the corresponding branch on the remote repository i.e. if another user has pushed changes to the remote you have to pull and solve possible conflicts before you can push.